# Probability of absorption in Markov chain with infinite state space

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

In a Markov chain with finite state space and absorbing states, if an absorbing state is reachable from every state, then it will absorb with probability $1$. The same does not hold true if there is an infinite state space (e.g. birth-death processes). I am looking to find this probability.

Let $M$ be the transition matrix so that each column adds up to $1$, the first $n$ states be the absorbing states ($p_{i \to i} = 1$), and the initial state be state $s$. Since $\sum_{m=1}^{n} (M^k)_{s \to m}$ is the probability of going from state $s$ to an absorbing state within $k$ steps, then $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{m=1}^{n} (M^k)_{s \to m}$$ should be the probability of absorption. Assuming this is correct, I run into a problem - how do I find $\lim_{k \to \infty} M^k$? This is raising an infinite matrix to $\infty$, which seems impossible.

**My question**:

What is the probability of eventual absorption in a Markov chain with infinite state space?

Comment: It's a nontrivial computational problem in general. Naturally it either absorbs or else "escapes to infinity" but calculating the probability to escape in the presence of an absorbing state is not really any easier than calculating the probability of absorption.

Comment: A common way that works in *specific* problems is to divide the space into a finite set $A_n$ that contains any absorbing states and an infinite set $B_n$ that contains everything else, such that $A_n$ increases as a set to contain the entire state space. Then treat any possible transitions from $A_n$ into $B_n$ as transitions into an absorbing "macrostate". Then you calculate the probability of absorbing *into the macrostate* vs into one of the other absorbing states. Then you send $n \to \infty$.

Comment: You can use this latter technique with, for example, a simple but not necessarily symmetric random walk on the nonnegative integers that absorbs at $0$, so you compute the probability to hit $0$ before $n$ and then send $n \to \infty$, which will give the probability of absorbing in the infinite state space chain. This probability in the finite state space setting is called the committor and there is a standard way to evaluate it using renewal theory. Let me know if an answer elaborating just a little bit on these comments will suffice for your needs.

Comment: By the way your method does *not* work because it double-counts: once a path has absorbed at time $k_0$, it gets counted again at all times $k \geq k_0$. You might be able to get it to work if you replace the row of the transition matrix corresponding to starting in the absorbing state with all zeros, I am not 100% sure about that though.

Comment: @Ian Can you explain that approach a bit more in an answer? Also I don't think my approach double counts because the sum is not over $k$, it is over the absorbing states.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right, I see what you are doing, yeah that will work fine, but you won't be able to do the multiplication in the general situation anyway (how would you do it, it's an infinite matrix!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle this is a nontrivial computational problem. A way to handle it that works in specific, sufficiently simple problems is to write your problem as a limit of finite problems. You do that in the following way. Introduce an increasing sequence of finite subsets $X_n$ of the state space $X$ such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n=X$. Now introduce a new absorbing state, let's just call it $\infty$ just because it's a fun name, and take the probabilities to transition into $\infty$ from inside $X_n$ to be the sum of all the probabilities to exit $X_n$ from each state in $X_n$ in the original chain.

Now we pose a slightly different question: what is the probability to absorb to one of the absorbing states in $X_n$ instead of $\infty$? Obviously this depends on where you start, as well as on $n$, so we can call it $q_n(x)$, and the dependence on the starting point satisfies the equation

$$q_n(x) = 1 \quad x \in A \cap X_n \\
q_n(\infty)= 0 \\
q_n(x) = \sum_{m \in X_n} p_{xm} q_n(m) \quad x \in X_n \setminus \{ A \cup \{ \infty \} \}$$

where $A$ is the set of absorbing states in the original chain. (This $q_n$ is probably a really bad approximation of the actual absorption probability in the original chain if $A \not \subset X_n$, so you might want to assume that $A \subset X_1$, which will simplify the notation a little bit anyway.)

This follows from conditioning on the first step. This system can at least in principle be solved for any finite $n$, and one can then try to send $n \to \infty$ to obtain the solution to the original question through $q_n$. Ideally the system would be simple enough that you could do this analytically, or you could just approximate by taking a large enough finite $n$ and solving the system numerically.

Comment: Just to make sure that I am understanding correctly, this approach splits the state space into three groups (actually absorbing [$A$], "middle", and fake absorbing [$\infty$] ) and then finds the limit of absorbing into $A$ rather than $\infty$ as the middle group approaches the whole state space (except for the absorbing states).

Comment: @VVejalla That's right.